# Explanation if patent is granted or pending

Tags: patentability, us

I am not a US citizen and I'm not fit into all these bureaucracy and complex names. 
How can I know if this patent was granted?

```
Publication number  US9117231 B2
Publication type    Grant
Application number  US 13/615,512
Publication date    Aug 25, 2015
Filing date Sep 13, 2012
Priority date   Jan 25, 2012
Also published as   US20130191229, WO2013110942A1
```

I can read `Grant`, but from [here](http://www.thomsonfilehistories.com/docs/RESOURCES_Kind%20Codes%20by%20Country.pdf) I read that B2 are `Reexamination Certificate Second Reexamination` (there is also a third step). 
My question is, was it definitely approved? Or it is still in someway pending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The patent is granted and currently valid in the US.

If you see "B2" (for US patents) that means the patent has been granted on the relevant date but you have to check what is the status of it *today*. The reason is that granted patents often are subject of invalidation or similar proceedings or the proprietor may have stop paying for them.

Also keep in mind that the kind code is different between countries or regions. In Europe granted patents are B1 and B2 stands usually for patents which were amended under opposition proceedings.

In general consult an attorney if the answer is important to you to make decisions.